# How to implement time dependence in the DoFun package?

Tags: packages, physics, functional

DoFun is a very usefull mathematica package that helps to write [Dyson-Schwinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation) and [FRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_renormalization_group) flow equations when these are to complex to write down by hand. You can download it [here](http://physik.uni-graz.at/~mqh/DoFun/) and read it's manual [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5307).

With my basic experience with DoFun, I find myself unable to tackle properly out-of-equilibrium problems where Feynmann diagramms contain an integration over momentum and **frequency**.

I tried to consider the frequency as another index with

```
defineFieldsSpecific[{δϕ[momentum, frequency]}];
```

For simplicity I consider a scalar field that has no other indices. This failed because the

```
delta[frequency,ω_1,ω_2]
```

function does not handle negative indices as expected. For example, mathematica does not know that

```
delta[frequency,-\[\omega]_1,\[\omega]_2] = delta[frequency,\[\omega]_1,-\[\omega]_2]
```

and the function `integrateDeltas` can not handle expressions such as

```
delta[frequency,-\[\omega]_1,\[\omega]_2] ω_1 \\integrateDeltas
```

Any help on how to include frequency into my vertices would be welcome. Tips on how to use the `delta` function better or suggestions to solve my problem in a completely different way are welcome and needed.